# how can I detect gin and gist

Tags: postgresql, indexing, gwt-gin, gist-index

how can I detect GIN and GiST indexes in postgresql? I am looking for if an database of postgres use fulltext. I think that a table use GIN o GiST then is using fulltext.

I accept that GIN or GiST indexes does not necessarily mean that they are used for full text search, but how can I differentiate them of other indexes type? I want to list Gin an Gist indexes

Comment: Presence of GIN or GiST indexes does not necessarily mean that they are used for full text search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index definitions can be recreated with `pg_get_indexdef()` from the [System Catalog Information Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE), fed by the `pg_index` system view. The output is theorically non-trivial to parse but in practice, a simple regexp is good enough to filter these definitions on certain index types.

For example, to find `gist` or `gin` indexes, you may use a query like this:

```
SELECT pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid) from pg_index
 WHERE pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid) ~ 'USING (gin |gist )';
```

To find if a certain database uses fulltext, I'd probably search for `tsvector` columns instead, with a query like this:

```
SELECT table_schema,table_name, column_name
 FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE data_type='tsvector';
```

Answer (score 4):

I dug around in the [Postgres source code](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/ruleutils_8c_source.html#l00997) and found that this information is stored in the `pg_am` table:

```
select i.relname, a.amname
from pg_index ix
left join pg_class i on ix.indexrelid = i.oid
left join pg_class t on ix.indrelid = t.oid
left join pg_am a on i.relam = a.oid
```